# strange behavior - Connection to ftp server

Tags: server, nautilus, ftp, filezilla

I installed an ftp server on my android phone. I can access it with filezilla, I can access it with Nautilus, but somehow, I can't access it from the terminal. Yet from the terminal, I can access another ftp server running on a ubuntu server machine.

[image: Successful on Filezilla]
[image: Successful on Nautilus][image: Failure on terminal]

Comment: The `ftp` command line syntax is `open host port` not `open host:port` AFAIK - try `open 192.168.1.254 1024`

Comment: It worked. Sorry for the stupid question. Thank you.